# Task.Delay is skipped

Tags: uwp, task

My goal is to play an audio file in uwp repeatedly. In between is a waitingtime, that changes.

The problem is that waitingtime is always skipped.

This is what I tried:

```
private async Task Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(delegate
        {
            abspielenAsync();
            return 42;
        });
        t.Wait();
    }
}

private async void abspielenAsync()
{
    if (neu)
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            mysong = new MediaElement();

        });
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("he.wav");
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            mysong.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        });
        neu = false;
    }
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            mysong.Play();
            while(mysong.CurrentState == Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.MediaElementState.Playing)
            {

            }
        });
    await Task.Delay((int)(waitingtime * 1000));
    Debug.WriteLine((waitingtime * 1000).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will always return immediately:

```
var t = Task.Run(delegate
        {
            abspielenAsync();
            return 42;
        });
        t.Wait();
```

Your `abspielenAsync` method is not returning a `Task`, so it cannot be awaited. So you're just running it in the background and not waiting for it (commonly called "fire and forget").

If you want to wait until `abspielenAsync()` is done before returning `42`, then make your `abspielenAsync` method return `Task` and change where you call it to `await abspielenAsync();`.

Answer (score -1):

@Gabriel tells us why the code does not run.

And we need to change the code in the `abspielenAsync` to make the task run.

```
private async void abspielenAsync()
```

We should change `void` to `Task` and `wait` it in the Task.

```
private async Task abspielenAsync()
```

Then we should change the code in Characteristic_ValueChanged

```
    while (true)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            await abspielenAsync();
            return 42;
        });
        t.Wait();
    }
```

The method name should be named as [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase). See [coding-style.md](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md)